# Flex: Remove all space around text in label

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, user-interface, text, components

If I create a `mx:Label` or `mx:Text` control in Flex and then set an opaqueBackground to it, I notice that there is some space around the text.

I would like to be able to get rid of that space to where the text is completely flush to the top and bottom of the label. Changing the gap, padding, and leading didn't seem to help. Is it possible to get the text completely flush to the sides of a label?

Thanks.

Comment: which of the paddings did you try? Does the container with the text in it apply any additional padding / gaps

Comment: What container with the text in it? The mx:Label or mx:Text? I don't know if it applys any more padding/gaps. I know that for both of those components I set paddingLeft, paddingRight, paddingTop, paddingBottom, verticalGap, horizontalGap to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the best way to do this (to remove ALL padding/spacing) is to actually use a wrapper (like Canvas) to wrap the label and customize as needed.

A bit ugly, but it was the only way I found.

Answer (score 1):

It's been some time since that question was asked, but I think the problem is that Label and Text add the value of UITextField.TEXT_HEIGHT_PADDING to some measuring stuff (measuredHeight in Text, lineMetrics in Label) and this causes those controls to appear a bit differently.

If you check, the current value of the UITextField.TEXT_HEIGHT_PADDING property is 4, however it is an mx_internal property. What I do is set the paddingTop to -2 and it seems to do the trick. I think that messing with measuredHeight would probably break some other stuff in Label and Text so I just fight it with padding...

Answer (score 0):

imho it should work in flex, same for height:

```
label.width = label.textWidth
```

Comment: This does not work. It simply starts to cut off the text portion of the label.

Answer (score -1):

You need to experiment with giving the Label negative paddingTop and paddingBottom until it's flush.